# Unit Testing a method that uses REST calls in Swift

Tags: json, swift, rest, unit-testing

Let me start out by stating I'm still unfamiliar with what I'm trying to do, but striving to get better!

I'm working on a project that I'm writing unit tests for and I'm having some trouble with how to approach the problem.

The method I'm testing utilizes a RESTAPI call to verify a users credentials. I'm not sure what the best way to unit test would be.

Here is the method I'm looking to make the Unit test for:

```
@IBAction func loginBtnActivate(sender: UIButton) {
    let enteredEmail: String = emailField.text!
    let enteredPassword: String = passwordField.text!
    let testInfo:[String: AnyObject] = ["User": enteredEmail, "Password": enteredPassword]
    RestApiManager.sharedInstance.postLogin(testInfo) { (json, statusCode) in
        if statusCode == 200 {
            let AuthToken: TokenObject = (TokenObject(json: json))
            try! self.keychain.set(AuthToken.Authorization, key:"Authorization")
            try! self.keychain.set(AuthToken.LifeTime, key: "LifeTime")
            try! self.keychain.set(AuthToken.UUID, key: "UUID")
             NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginToMyHealth", sender: nil)
            }
        } else if statusCode == 401 {
            self.incorrectLoginAlert()
        } else if statusCode == 503 {
            print("Service Unavailable Please Try Again Later")
        }
    }
}
```

This is currently the approach I'm taking:

```
 func testLoginInfoMatchesDataOnServer(){
    let enteredEmail: String = "user"
    let enteredPassword: String = "password"
    let testInfo:[String: AnyObject] = ["User": enteredEmail, "Password": enteredPassword]
    RestApiManager.sharedInstance.postLogin(testInfo) { (json, statusCode) in
    XCTAssert(statusCode == 200, "statusCode is not matching the server data")
}
```

I'm simply verifying that the Rest call is successful and that the credentials are matching the JSON. The XCTAssert call doesn't appear to be working correctly. No matter what I put as the first parameter, XCTAssert doesn't affect whether the test is successful or not.

Example, if I put:

```
XCTAssert(false, "statusCode is not matching the server data")
```

The test will still pass regardless of what I put. If I place the Assert function outside the brackets then it appears the variable "statusCode" is out of scope so I'm stuck with a

> Use of unresolved identifier 'statusCode'.

```
   func testLoginInfoMatchesDataOnServer(){
let enteredEmail: String = "user"
let enteredPassword: String = "password"
let testInfo:[String: AnyObject] = ["User": enteredEmail, "Password": enteredPassword]
RestApiManager.sharedInstance.postLogin(testInfo) { (json, statusCode) in
}
XCTAssert(statusCode == 200, "statusCode is not matching the server data")
}
```

I was looking at this guide for help.. Would this be a better approach for what I'm trying to do?

http://roadfiresoftware.com/2016/06/how-do-you-unit-test-rest-calls-in-swift/

Again my understanding of some core concepts might be entirely off so I really appreciate your advice here!

Thanks in advance!

Sean W.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First Few problems with your code

```
function test(){    
    RestApiManager.sharedInstance.postLogin(testInfo) { (json, statusCode) in

    }//PostLogin call ends
    XCTAssert(statusCode == 200, "statusCode is not matching the server data") // Here StatusCode is not accessible as outside the block
}// end function
```

If you want to use Status Code you should do

```
function test(){    
    RestApiManager.sharedInstance.postLogin(testInfo) { (json, statusCode) in
        XCTAssert(statusCode == 200, "statusCode is not matching the server data") // Here StatusCode is accessible inside the block
    }//PostLogin call ends
}// end function
```

But this will fail since you need to wait for the response. That can be done using

> waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5)

So proper way to call this would be --

```
function test(){    
    let URL = NSURL(string: "http://google.com/")!
    let expectation = expectationWithDescription("GET \(URL)")
    RestApiManager.sharedInstance.postLogin(testInfo) { (json, statusCode) in
        XCTAssert(statusCode == 200, "statusCode is not matching the server data") // Here StatusCode is accessible inside the block
        expectation.fulfill()
    }//PostLogin call ends
    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5){ error in 
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }//Wait block end
}// end function
```

Important lines here are

> expectation.fulfill() // tells process is complete

and

> waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5){} //tells wait for 5secs or throw error

For more [info](http://nshipster.com/xctestcase/)

Comment: I think this is exactly what I needed katch! Thank you!

Comment: A quick follow up, should I be setting up my unit tests like this? I've read that this is technically integration testing instead of unit testing. Should I be working with local files instead to avoid relying on a call to a server?

I'm only asking if you happen to know off hand. Otherwise, I'll keep doing more research.

Thanks again!

Comment: I think its a separate question. But I would recommend both offline and online. Offline using json files etc & online using actual calls

Comment: You can start here http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/07/09/fixture-data-for-ios-tests/ for offline. I am working on it at the moment, so if I have something ready I will upload to github to show